# Custom functions onclick within qtip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, tampermonkey

I'm inserting `qtips` from a userscript through tampermonkey, which is being loaded after the page is loaded. I can't seem to be able to get custom Javascript functions working from inside a tooltip (`qtip`). I keep getting reference errors, saying that the function that I want to call is not defined. Could someone please explain why? (error messages taken from Chrome beta latest)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: redirectAH is not defined index.php?cmd=news:1
onclick
```

Code:

```
//headers that work fine
$( function() {

    GM_addStyle(GM_getResourceText('qtipCSS'));

    (function redirectAH(playerID){
        window.location = 'http://domain.com/index.php?data1=cmd&data2=-5&pid=' + playerID;
        //correct format for above: http://domain.com/index.php?data1=cmd&data2=-5&pid=123456 or any sort of other PID
        return;
    })();

    var makeConfig = function(jqObject){

        var playerID = something; //code to define it correctly
        var arrLen = jqObject.attr('href').split('player_id=').length || -1;
        var playerID = 0;
        if (arrLen > 0){
            playerID = jqObject.attr('href').split('player_id=')[arrLen -1];
        }
        var argumentAH = '<span onclick="javascript:redirectAH(playerID)"> [AH] </span>';

        var finalText = '<div style = "text-align: center;">' + 'PID: ' + playerID + '<br/>'+ argumentAH + '</div>';

        var qtipContent = {
            overwrite: false,
            content: { text: finalText, attr: 'error' },
            position: { my: 'bottom left', at: 'top left', adjust: {    method: 'shift none' } },
            show: { delay: 50 },
            hide: { fixed: true, delay: 90 },
            style: { classes: 'qtip-tipsy qtip-shadow' }
        };

        return qtipContent;
    };

    $('[href *= "index.php"]').each(function(){     
        if (this.textContent.trim()){
            var inputHTML = $(this);
            var config = makeConfig(inputHTML);
            $(this).qtip(config);
        }
    });
});
```

I *think* that wrapping the `redirectAH()` is supposed to add the function to the global scope, but I am still having issues so I guess that is not happening. Since this link has to change with every `qtip`, which doesn't get rendered until someone hovers over a player's name, I don't know how else to do this (I can't assign ID and do it later since the qtip may not have been loaded when that function runs. Also, the player data would be lost and I'd have to rip it again). Maybe it has something to do with the tampermonkey sandbox, though I don't know how to fix it.

I'm also getting continuous errors of the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasClass' of null libs.js?ver=00120:14353
    inactiveMethod libs.js?ver=00120:14353
    (anonymous function) libs.js?ver=00120:14392
    jQuery.event.special.(anonymous function).handle libs.js?ver=00120:3535
    jQuery.event.dispatch libs.js?ver=00120:3256
    elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

EDIT: HTML snipped that is returned when calling `$('[href *= "index.php"]')`

```
<a href="index.php?player_id=######" class="someclass" style="">playerName</a>
```

I've updated the main code with the code that I'm using to strip the playerID.

Comment: A few issues, but the most important one is don't use `onclick`! (Pretty much EVER, but especially in TM scripts.)  In this case, use jQuery's `.on()`.  Also, looking at the page's HTML, how do you determine `playerID`?  The click event handler can determine that on the fly, but we need to know the appropriate HTML snippet for that.

Comment: PS:  from your previous question, `$(this).qtip(config);` should now be: `inputHTML.qtip(config);`.  (We assign the variable to avoid jQuery encapsulating the exact same object more than once.)

Comment: Hi Brock. I've updated the main post with an html snipped for what each element of the jquery selection looks like. If I was to use `.on()`, where would be the best place to add the handlers for the links inside the tooltips? I *believe* they don't actually get added into the DOM until they're hovered over, and isn't it too late by that time?